# Is it a software bug? Why getting Q&(accepted)A to the front?

Tags: support

I've seen [What is a neutral atom?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/738/24114);
it is a question, it has an accepted answer, but (maybe I have some misconceptions about that) is "refreshed" by the "Community" user.

Please help me understand.

Comment: For reference, we call "getting to the front" or "refresh" **bumps**. "The post was bumped by the community user" is the sentence I'd use with sheer SE jargon. :) The bot does bump random questions, but IIRC the bumped questions were unanswered ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug.

There was an answer that was marked as spam, offensive or nonsense. The answer and the user were therefore deleted.
This intervention is indicated as “modified … ago [Community ♦](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) 1”.

Note that you need 10 000 reputation on this site to [view deleted posts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: OK, but why then is the question "bumped" by that? So, say, if I'd pay someone to place some spam on my question, would it be visible as "newly active" by community deleting the spam? Doesn't look right.

Comment: @Gyro there should be an indication of activity. Since well, there *was* activity. I don't think anyone gains anything by having their question active again, other than a few eventual upvotes which come and go anyway. What could be more concerning for you would be the [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect?s=1|4.0207) that comes with this which tends to be far greater.

Comment: @IͶΔ "there should be an indication of activity" yea, but no *promotion* from this kind of activity. "meta effect" is far more complicated.

Comment: How is it promotion? @Gyro

Comment: @IͶΔ it is promotion because it is put on the front of the "active" list, a place to gain more views.

Comment: Bah, I don't see it as such @Gyro. The active tab gets flushed down every couple of hours. It's not like stuff is sitting there for us to visit. Some people (including me) don't even use that tab.

Comment: @IͶΔ, well OK, then it is ignored by custom usage (tradition, local culture). On other stackexchange sites, frequency of post and view is drastically different. *chemistry* here looks like a neglected orphan.

Comment: Not really @Gyro. More users brings more questions and hence the per-question view is very similar in big or small SEs (Don't have data to back this up tho'). Also, there are established users who do use the active tab (like Ron). What I *do* know is that it's not a big deal -- An ordinary bump doesn't garner the additional views you think it does in **any** SE.

Comment: @IͶΔ "An ordinary bump doesn't garner the additional view..." I have different experience.  When I had to fix some typos, some time after posting, I've got more views.

Answer (score 5):

I do a little bit disagree with Loong's assessment. Here is the events in order:

- The question was answered at 17:24:52Z. This caused the question to get bumped to the top of the active page. At this time there was still a username attached to the post, so it would have read "modified ... ago user666"
- It was immediately flagged as "low quality" by the community user.
- At 17:26:11Z, a little more than a minute later, the post was deleted by the community user. This was caused by jonsca with an offensive flag.
  At the same time it was locked by the community user.
  Note that up to this point the post was still attached to a user.
- At 17:26:35Z the user was deleted as the intention of this account is to post nonsense or spam.
  At this point there was no more user that could be shown as the one that modified the post.
  In these cases the Community user will jump in and take the blame. This is why after that time it read "modified ... ago Community"
  Posts do not get debumped when deleted.

**TL;DR** The bump was caused by the creation of the post. The user was deleted as well as the post. Since no user could be shown, the Community user was shown instead.

*Extra info* The deletion of a post does not bump a question. This happens silently.